# django write csv file

Tags: django, csv

I am trying to get ajax data and output csv file using django, however, tutorial code works:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.csv'
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"]) 
return response
```

but my code doest work!

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.csv' 
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"]) 
    return response
```

any suggestions ?!

Comment: also for sure, I import csv

Comment: I didnt see any difference!!! wdf

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a post request. It's a get request. Remove the if method == post.

Comment: actually, im using a post to pass some data to filter out what to output as csv file. I havent try it without POST, but why response not independent?

Comment: what i am thinking is, if method==POST is just a condition, not effect on rest of codes.

Comment: Ah, not enough context in the main question to deduce that you were filtering the results. It could be there that's the problem. How are you calling the view? Are you visiting a url or submitting a form? Are you getting any errors?